# using exceptions and transactions in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception, transactions, stripe-payments

I've got a page that processes a customer order, and I'm running into some transaction (from a general sense) issues.

I use two external services (namely Stripe for CC processing, and Postmaster for shipping). I call those two services in a `try` block, and `catch` any exceptions they send. if that passes I create a DB entry on my end.  With my current logic, my concern is that if the Stripe and Postmaster calls succeed, and my database insert fails, I have no way to rollback the Stripe and Postmaster calls.  Is there a best practice for something like this?

I am using Codeigniter MVC, so my db insert is done by calling a model method that returns either true or false.

General Idea:

```
try{
    //create charge and shipment
    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create();

//create shipment
$shipment = $this->postmaster->shipment_create();
}

catch{
    //stripe and postmaster exceptions
}

$this->order_model->addOrder();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write to the database as soon as possible. Record the state of the "transaction" in the database (e.g. *unprocessed*, *sent to stripe*, *sent to postmaster*). In case of failure, restore a consistent state from information aquired from the DB, Stripe and Postmaster. You need to query Stripe and Postmaster, because the failure might have occurred when the state should have been updated.

You cannot influence the availability of Stripe and Postmaster, but you can always make your database more reliable.

Comment: i'm a little confused by your answer, but i did like the overall suggestion. I'm not sure that I want to record a 'state' of the transaction in the db, I want it to not exist if something fails. also, stripe and postmaster return an 'id' of some sorts that I'd like to enter into the db as well. obviously this can't be done first. should this be a separate query after the try/catch?

Comment: If you store the stripe- and postmaster-id, then these fields can be used to record and retrieve the state information. Initially set the fields to NULL. As soon as you have the stripe id, update the corresponding field with that id. As soon as you have the postmaster id, update the corresponding field with that id.

Comment: don't I run into the same initial problem then? if I `try/catch` the stripe method, get an ID returned to me, try and update my DB with this ID, and that update fails, the stripe charge has been created but I don't have a record of it.  I think basically what the issue comes down to, is there needs to be a way to 'pair' external service calls with DB calls, so they call all be committed or rolled backed. maybe it's not currently possible? i don't know, and if not I'll just do the best i can

Comment: You need to make sure that you do not lose any vital information. If the initial database insert fails, you can catch that error and at worst ask the customer to come back later. If the subsequent stripe call fails, you can call stripe at a later time. If updating the database with the strip id fails, hopefully stripe provides you with an API to recover the stripe id at a later time using the database record. By "at a later time", I don't mean the `catch` block. The best you can do in the `catch` block is use a failover DB, send an E-Mail to the staff and provide feedback to the user.

Comment: so basically it seems like there's no perfect solution for this, just do the best we can.  also i want to make sure we're understanding each other on one part. you wrote 'If the subsequent stripe call fails, you can call stripe at a later time.' are you suggesting that I accept the order and try charging the credit card at a later time? is this allowed or good practice?

Comment: I argued from a technical point of view. Whether you accept the order without the confirmation from stripe (my guess is, there is some financial risk involved), whether you put the order on hold, whether you cancel the order are business descisions. Storing the DB record only if stripe and postmaster succeeds narrows down the business descissions that you can make (to the point where if one of them is down, reject the order). Storing the DB record early and keeping state information gives you a wider range of possible paths through the ordering process.